# Car Truck Rigging problems

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I am rigging a dump truck with bones and parenting with empty groups and everything is articulating very good when I test the armature in object mode: dump goes up and down, doors open and close, etc. (Picture 1)
[image]

But, when I play the animation, everything goes apart (Picture 2.
[image]

Can anybody help me to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's difficult to understand which is the problem with so little infos, maybe you should upload your .blend file. Did you animate the Truck or the armature bones only? In the first case, that is the problem: the object location should stay still, while all vertices should be moved by one or more bones.

Comment: You are right. I put Ik's only on truck and wheels before parenting with the bones wich means that the armature and it's respectives vertices didn't get the Ik's applied. That's why some vertices still in rest position and some just...  I delete all the IK's and put all vertices-bones in a rest position and it works, Thank you very much.